# How to find 35mm equivalent focal length?

Tags: android

I can get focal length easily but I am not able to find 35mm equivalent focal length.

If anybody knows how to find 35mm equivalent focal length then please let me know. I have tried using ex if interface and hardware camera.

Comment: Where are you looking for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 35mm equivalent would be your obtained focal length multiplied by a certain number, known as crop factor.  This factor is very much different for different manufacturers and even models.  For example, for many Nikon DSLR cameras it's 1.5; for many Canon DSLRs it's 1.6; for Apple iPhone 5 it's 6.99, for Samsung Galaxy S3 it's 7.6, and so on.

To the best of my knowledge, Android does not provide an API to determine the crop factor of the device's camera.

There's one trick you can try using though. Once you take a photo with the device's camera, some devices will populate `FocalLengthIn35mmFilm` exif tag - so you can try using this technique.  Not all phones do this though, for example, my Huawei doesn't.

Some other devices will populate two fields for `Focal Length` - the first being the actual focal length used, the second being the 35mm equivalent.  Again, not all do.  The same Huawei phone doesn't, but my iPhone 5 does.

To make the long story short, there's no guaranteed way of figuring out the 35mm equivalent from the focal length you obtain on the device.

Comment: Could you halp me please with the same issue, i try to get info according your suggest, but we need i TAG to get exact property. For example for `focal lenght` there is `TAG_FOCAL_LENGHT` , but there is not TAG for `35 focal length` or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko The main point in my answer is that there is no sure way of getting it. You can try things that I mentioned in my answer, but nine is guaranteed to work. If you re dealing with a specific device, then you can find out the crop factor of that devices's camera and calculate it that way, otherwise you are out of luck, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to calculate it by first obtaining the sensor physical size and then using that to convert the focal length into 35mm equivalent:

```
float sensorWidth = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE).getWidth();
float focalLength = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)[0];
float focalLengthIn35mm = (36 * focalLength) / sensorWidth;
```